# Bizzare Pandas.read_html error

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup, lxml

I have some code I'm using to scrape a webpage. That code looks like:

```
for pages in pagesToScrape:
     print('test')
     url = 'http://myurl.com' + str(pages)
     page = pandas.read_html(url, attrs={'class': 'tableToRead'}, header = 0)  # Scrape web page
     print('hi')  # This is never printed for some reason
```

as stated in the comments, for some reason any code underneath the pandas.read_html line is never executed but I receive no error message either. This code worked 2 months ago so I'm wondering if something changed either with lxml, BeautifulSoup4, or one of their dependencies since the web page has not changed at all. I've also verified that the URL I'm using is valid. For additional testing I've also tried:

```
for pages in pagesToScrape:
         print('test')
         url = 'http://myurl.com' + str(pages)
         page = pandas.read_html(url, attrs={'class': 'tableToRead'}, header = 0)  # Scrape web page
         print(page)  # Doesn't print anything
         fasidfoaisdf()  # This non-existent function does not throw an error ever either...
```

Does anyone have any ideas why this could be happening? I feel like at the very least I could get the non-existent function to throw an error but the program compiles just fine and even runs through the for loop printing test everytime.

Python v3.5.3

BeautifulSoup4 v4.6.0

bs4 v0.0.1

lxml v3.7.3

EDIT: I've also tried removing the 'header = 0' from the read_html function call and that changes nothing.

Comment: It looks like you have "wrong" exception handling somwehre in your script around your loop. And this exception handling just ignores exceptions

Comment: Aw that did it. I added a try / except and had the except print out the error. I tried doing that earlier but for some reason never thought to try to print out the specific error. Guess that's what late nights do to ya. I'm going to paste the full solution below for anyone else that has this problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone else has this problem it turns out when I changed the code to:

```
for pages in pagesToScrape:
     print('test')
     url = 'http://myurl.com' + str(pages)
     try:     
         page = pandas.read_html(url, attrs={'class': 'tableToRead'}, header = 0)  # Scrape web page
     except Exception as e:
         print(e)
     print('hi')  # This is never printed for some reason
```

I got the correct error message which in my case was html5lib not being installed. Thanks MaxU!